# How to highlight active slides in Flexslider carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

Is it possible to highlight the current items in Flexslider carousel, so I can add a class to the active ones?

I use the basic setup of the Flexslider carousel. Now I would like to have a script that will added active to each slide inside the viewport that is visible.

This example I use:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html

I now how to get the Flexslider properties in the start function. When I give the function the parameter I can ask for - the total amount of items in the ul, how many items it will move, and how many paging there will be. I don't know if it is possible to write a formule to calculate which one is active with the given variables, so I can highlight them.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 460,
        itemMargin: 30,
        minItems: 2,
        maxItems: 6,
        controlNav: false,
        customDirectionNav: ".custom-direction li a",
        start: function(slider) {
            var pagingCount = slider.pagingCount;
            var move = slider.move;
            var visibleSlides = slider.visible;
            var totalSlides = slider.count;

            console.log(slider);
            console.log(slider.move);
            console.log(slider.update);


            if (totalSlides) {
                $('.slides li').addClass('active-slides');

            };
            // console.log(slider.count);
            // console.log(slider.currentSlide);
        }

    });
```

I have made a start, but doesn't know how the if statement or for loop should look like to get this done.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this you plugin http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html ?

Comment: @KishoreSahas Yes that one I use. What I would like to have is add the class active to each slide that is in the viewport. I have update my post of my progress right now..

Comment: try this . http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/a2jro8vt/1/

Comment: try replacing the image llinks. .. or better try the logic in your code ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the events `start` and 'after' to handle this. see the below example.

```js
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 460,
    itemMargin: 30,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 6,
    controlNav: false,
    customDirectionNav: ".custom-direction li a",
    start: function (slider) {
        window.addCurrentSlidesClass(slider);
    },
    after: function (slider) {
        window.addCurrentSlidesClass(slider);
    }
});

window.addCurrentSlidesClass = function (slider) {
    //debugger;
    $('.flexslider li').removeClass("active-slides");
    var startli = (slider.move * (slider.currentSlide));
    var endli = (slider.move * (slider.currentSlide + 1));
    for (i = startli + 1; i <= endli; i++) {
        $('.flexslider li:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('active-slides');
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexslider carousel">
    <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <ul class="slides" style="width: 2400%; transition-duration: 0.6s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
            <li style="width: 210px; float: left; display: block;">
                <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" draggable="false">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
        <li><a class="flex-active">1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="">2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="">3</a>

        </li>
    </ol>
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>

        </li>
        <li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#" tabindex="-1">Next</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="flex-pauseplay"><a class="flex-pause">Pause</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/a2jro8vt/1/)</kbd>

Comment: try this ... http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/a2jro8vt/8/ .. update the answer also ..

Comment: One more thing, is there a way, if the carousel length is odd, and the slider is on the last slide like index 4, to highlight the previous one? Now it only highlight index 4, but if there is a possibility to highlight also index 3 if 4 is odd would be absolute nice.

Answer (score 0):

Used the accepted answer above but needed to make a couple amendments to make it work for me shown below.

Mostly handling some exceptions, dealing with half shown slides and when the move/visible are different.

```
window.addCurrentSlidesClass = function (slider) {
  jQuery('.flexslider li').removeClass("active-slide");

  // get visible by math rather than slider variable due to half shown slides not counting
  // var visible = slider.visible;
  var visible = Math.ceil(slider.w / slider.itemT);

  var startli = (slider.move * (slider.currentSlide));
  // var endli = (slider.move * (slider.currentSlide + 1));
  var endli = startli + visible;

  // Don't push past when you reach end of list
  if(endli > slider.count) {
    startli = startli - (endli - slider.count);
    endli = endli - (endli - slider.count);
  }

  for (i = startli + 1; i <= endli; i++) {
    jQuery('.flexslider li:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('active-slide');
  }
};
```